# How to histogram yuv file to clear the image in C language

Tags: c, image-processing

I want to blurr and clear and sharpen an image but i dont know how to use mathematic formulas like histogram and averaging into a code. The image is already converted into yuv so the only problem is the maths formulas to finish the job. Can someone help me?

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned char yplane[240][416]; //array for the y component i.e. your greyscale image
unsigned char uplane[120][208]; //array for the u component. Needed to create the .yuv output file
unsigned char vplane[120][208]; //array for the v component. Needed to create the .yuv output file

int main()
{
FILE *fd;
FILE *fd2;

fd = fopen("PATH of file yuv", "rb");
fd2 = fopen("PATH of file yuv", "wb");

fread(yplane, 1, sizeof(yplane), fd);
fread(uplane, 1, sizeof(uplane), fd);
fread(vplane, 1, sizeof(vplane), fd);

/*
code to handle one or more of the components
For example the y component can be "seen" as a greyscale image with dimension 416X240
So, the data or the raw image are already stored in the yplane[240][416] array.
*/
fwrite(yplane, 1, sizeof(yplane), fd2);
fwrite(uplane, 1, sizeof(uplane), fd2);
fwrite(vplane, 1, sizeof(vplane), fd2);

fclose(fd2);
fclose(fd);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please check and improve your question. What is *"roil,clear"*? What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: @Gerhardh Ok, I'm intrigued. How did you work out that `roil` is `blur`?  

Comment: @MarkSetchell that's maaaaagic. :)  Well, I didn't. I only fixed the formatting for the dangling braces. Blur was alread fixed by the OP before my change. See edit history. ;)